# Disable db/schema.rb comments in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've been getting sick of seeing the "helpful" comments in the db/schema.rb after each migration. I've figured out how to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

To stop this from happening create the following file in `lib/tasks/schema_cleanup.rake` (note the `.rake`):

```
namespace :db do

  def cleanup_schema

    filename = "db/schema.rb"

    schema = File.read(filename)
             .split("\n")
             .select { |l| not l.strip.starts_with? "#" }
             .slice(1..-1)
             .push("")
             .join("\n")

    File.open(filename, 'w') do |file|
      file.write(schema)
    end

  end

  task :migrate do
    cleanup_schema
  end

end
```

Now each time you run the command the comments will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

As idea how to avoid adding comments in `schema.rb` you can add for example `lib/tasks/db.rake`:

```rb
namespace :db do
  at_exit do
    schema_filename = Rails.root.join('db', 'schema.rb')

    break unless File.exist?(schema_filename)

    schema = File.readlines(schema_filename, chomp: true).grep_v(/#/)
    File.open(schema_filename, 'w') { |file| file.puts schema }
  end
end
```

In this case every time you invoke any task in `db` namespace, this code will be executed in the end and **all lines with comments** will be removed

Of course you can modify this code for your specific needs